# I need to number by a given observation and order

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to number the observations given the following order and to restart when the value offer_start is reached

```
evconv <- s%>% 
  arrange(id, time) %>% 
  select(id,time,name)
```

```
evconv$name=="offer_start"
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[20] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I need to get something like this:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 1 2 3 4 5
[20] 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea using `rle`,

```
x <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)

sequence(colSums(matrix(rle(x)$lengths, ncol = 2)))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3
```